# Problema de enrutamiento laravel 5.8

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Cuando pongo `127.0.0.1:8000/productAjax` que es una pagina de prueba que estoy realizando en `laravel`, queda buscando la pagina y si pongo `127.0.0.1:8000/blog/productAjax` pasa exactamente lo mismo. y no encuentro que puede pasar..

Comment: Necesitamos ver código para poder ayudar. ¿Cómo están configuradas las rutas y el servidor?

Comment: @shaz _no tengo configurado ningun servidor y las rutas la tengo configurada de esta manera_ 

Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
    return view('productAjax');
});

//ruta de recursos
Route::resource('ajaxproducts','ProductAjaxController');

Comment: No veo que esté definida la ruta productAjax ni la ruta blog/productAjax.

Comment: @Shaz como hago para definir esas rutas? te pregunto porque soy nuevo en laravel

Comment: ¿Qué pretendes acceder con dichas rutas?

Comment: estoy queriendo realizar un crud a una base de datos. y copie un ejemplo pero me salta ese error

Comment: OK pero ¿es un controlador, un closure? puntualmente...

Comment: la pagina que quiero llamar es un blade

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si lo que deseas es acceder a una vista Blade sin pasar por un controlador o similar, puedes utilizar el método view en el código que define la vista:

```
Route::view('/productAjax', 'productAjax');
```

El primer parámetro es la ruta como tal desde la que se accederá, y el segundo parámetro es el nombre de la vista blade.

Esto quiere decir que la ruta  `/productAjax` va a acceder directamente a la vista blade ubicada en `resources/views/productAjax.blade.php`

Por favor revisa la documentación de rutas para mayor información: https://laravel.com/docs/master/routing

Comment: muchas gracias he probado de esa manera y funciona!..